# Securing SDK - best practices

Tags: android, sdk, obfuscation

I am looking for guidance on securing an SDK that I am working on and will be distributing to developers. Here are some of the items I want to consider and was looking for pointers on best practices:

- Code Obfuscation
- Debugging with source - not possible if I obfuscate the code
- Secure (or encrypt) files that the SDK would create and access but not make available to developers
- Prevent any Security holes in the SDK

Comment: This is very broad for a Stack Overflow question (and, in truth, is not actually a question). For that matter, [they are debating what to do about questions with "best practices" in the title](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312021/prevent-eliminate-best-practices-from-titles). I recommend that you break this up into four questions, one per bullet, where you ask **specific questions**. You might also consider reviewing [the site documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for advice on writing questions.

Comment: Understood. Thank you Mark.